# Improvement on data normalization

Tags: python, numpy

I have a part of code that is loading a dataset and normalizing property values to [0, 1]. My implementation is:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

# -- load data
prop_1    = list(np.random.rand(10)*20)
prop_2    = list(np.random.rand(10)*10)
prop_3    = list(np.random.rand(10)*30)

# -- normalize
l_bound = []
l_bound.append(min(prop_1))
l_bound.append(min(prop_2))
l_bound.append(min(prop_3))
u_bound = []
u_bound.append(max(prop_1))
u_bound.append(max(prop_2))
u_bound.append(max(prop_3))

prop_1 = (np.array(prop_1) - l_bound[0]) / (u_bound[0] - l_bound[0])
prop_2 = (np.array(prop_2) - l_bound[1]) / (u_bound[1] - l_bound[1])
prop_3 = (np.array(prop_3) - l_bound[2]) / (u_bound[2] - l_bound[2])
```

However, the normalizing part of the code does not look graceful. Any suggestions on how to improve it? Can do this using a loop?

Comment: Can you show the result of `prop_*` as loaded by `pickle`?

Comment: Also, why are you loading the same file three times?

Comment: It's not the same file, it's 3 separate variables. Each variable is a list of property values for 2000 molecules.

Comment: It... definitely looks like the same file to me. You use `f` three times. What am I missing?

Comment: That's just how pickle works, you save data using:    `with open(dataset_name, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(prop_1, f)
        pickle.dump(prop_2, f)
        pickle.dump(prop_3, f)`

Comment: OK; so it's one file containing three separate sections. Fair enough. Can you show an example of a couple of molecules? Otherwise this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Ah, I just mentioned that to clear things up, otherwise, I'm dealing with properties only in this subsection. So essentially, I'm loading 3 properties, then find lower and upper bounds for each list of property values, and then normalize each list so that the final output is in the interval [0,1]. Now, what I don't like is that I can't write a loop [it is possible I guess, I had few unsuccessful attempts though]. So if I had 10 properties, I would have had a longer script. So I was wondering if you can suggest how to write the normalization part in a loop

Comment: Again. Please show sample data in the question. This question currently does not have enough context to be on-topic.

Comment: I see that loading data is confusing you. I updated the data loading part.

Comment: What kind of data are you serializing/loading?

Comment: @AMC 3 lists of floats, using pickle.

Comment: @Blade Lists? Is your code meant to work with numpy arrays, or plain Python lists?

Comment: @AMC Non. It is supposed to be 'torch.Tensor'. But my data generation script is consist of a loop over inputs (molecules) and computes them using cheminformatic packages and is using 'append' to create my property vector. That's why it is a list. later on I convert it to torch tensor.

Comment: @AMC Also, the only reason I use numpy here is to mimic my data, nothing else.

Comment: @Blade _But my data generation script is consist of a loop over inputs (molecules) and computes them using cheminformatic packages and is using 'append' to create my property vector. That's why it is a list. later on I convert it to torch tensor._ Ah, alright. I was just asking to try to figure out if there is a better solution than using pickle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have `numpy` arrays, you should use their vectorized methods wherever possible. This can make your code a lot faster:

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(10000000)

In [2]: %timeit max(x)
988 ms ± 42.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit x.max()
9.67 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This includes not casting your arrays to `list`.

I would also make this a function that normalizes a single array:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from typing import Iterable, Any

def normalize_one(x: Iterable[Any]) -> np.ndarray:
    if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = np.array(list(x))
    low, diff = x.min(), x.ptp()
    return (x - low) / diff

# -- load data
prop_1    = np.random.rand(10)*20
prop_2    = np.random.rand(10)*10
prop_3    = list(np.random.rand(10)*30

# -- normalize
prop_1 = normalize_one(prop_1)
prop_2 = normalize_one(prop_2)
prop_3 = normalize_one(prop_3)
```

If you do have many arrays that need to be normalized, you can always do it in a list comprehension:

```
properties = [prop_1, prop_2, prop_3]
properties = [normalize_one(prop) for prop in properties]
```

If you have many of them and they all have the same structure, I would use something like this (now limited to `numpy` arrays as input):

```
def normalize(x: np.ndarray, axis: int = 1) -> np.ndarray:
    """Normalize the array to lie between 0 and 1.
    By default, normalizes each row of the 2D array separately.
    """
    low, diff = x.min(axis=axis), x.ptp(axis=axis)
    # Indexing needed to help numpy broadcasting
    return (x - low[:,None]) / diff[:,None]

properties = np.random.rand(3, 10)
properties[0] *= 20
properties[1] *= 10
properties[2] *= 30

properties = normalize(properties)
```

For `props = np.random.rand(10000, 10)` I get the following timings:

```
Author      Timed function call                       Time [s]
Blade*      list(normalize_blade(props))              68.7 ms ± 749 µs
Linny       list(normalize_linny(*props))             127 ms ± 1.42 ms
Graipher    [normalize_one(prop) for prop in props]   119 ms ± 7.4 ms
Graipher    normalize(props)                          2.32 ms ± 113 µs
```

The code I used for the test with the code in the OP is this one, which is just the generalization to many properties:

```
def normalize_blade(properties):
    l_bound, u_bound = [], []
    properties = [list(prop) for prop in properties]
    for prop in properties:
        l_bound.append(min(prop))
        u_bound.append(max(prop))
    for i, prop in enumerate(properties):
        yield (np.array(prop) - l_bound[i]) / (u_bound[i] - l_bound[i])
```

Comment: strange that `normalize_one` is slower than `normalize_blade`, using the list appends and builtin `min` and `max` instead of the `numpy methods`

Comment: @MaartenFabré I agree, I was also surprised. It might be due to the `isinstance`, but I'm not sure. Or maybe `numpy.ptp` is slower than `numpy.max` plus one subtraction. Also, note that each property is only 10 elements long, as in the OP, so the built-in operations are still quite fast. If you see any obvious mistakes in my timing, let me know.

Comment: I don't see why it's slower either. If you write it as `    low, high = x.min(), x.max()
    return (x - low) / (high - low)` instead with `ptp` is about 25% faster, but still slower than OP. Removing the `isinstance` and `list` speeds it up a bit, but still not enough

Answer (score 4):

## keep your raw data

You overwrite `props_x` with the normalized version. Better would be to make this a new variable

## data structures

If you have more than 1 or 2 properties. Assigning them each to their own variable can become quite tedious. You need to gather them in a data structure. If they are all of the same length, a `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` can be the right structures. 
Otherwise a `dict` might be more appropriate

```
data_raw = {
    "prop_1": list(np.random.rand(10) * 20),
    "prop_2": list(np.random.rand(10) * 10),
    "prop_3": list(np.random.rand(10) * 30),
}
```

## function

Almost each time you write a comment in your code denoting a section, you can make the code itself clearer by putting that section in a data structure, function, class, ...

```
def normalize(iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> np.array:
    """Linearly scales the input to the interval [0, 1]"""
    my_array = np.array(list(iterable))
    lower, upper = my_array.min(), my_array.max()
    return (my_array - lower) / (upper - lower)
```

I even added a docstring explaining what the method does.

```
data_normalized = {
    name: normalize(data)
    for name, data in data_raw.items()
}
```

## spacing

For code formatting, I trust [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) to make the correct choices for me.So no more `prop_1    =`, but 1 space around the `=`, ...

The only coniguration I use there is maximum 79 character per line.

Black integrates wellwith most IDEs and jupyter lab notebooks ([docs](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor_integration.html))

Answer (score 2):

I took a stab at this, not really knowing what you wanted. The function below yields the outcome of each calculation made in your program. You can pass any amount of `np.array` to it, aka any iterables, and it will make the calculation based on what you passed. Have a look:

```
from typing import Iterable, Any
import numpy as np

def normalize(*iterables: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[np.array]:
    for iterable in iterables:
        my_array = np.array(list(iterable))
        lower, upper = my_array.min(), my_array.max()
        yield (my_array - lower) / (upper - lower)
```

Thanks to [@Maarten Fabré](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/123200/maarten-fabr%C3%A9) for pointing out that real iterables were excluded from this program, and would fail. It now works with these, as displayed below. This function also now complies with PEP 0484 type hints regarding iterables.

Here's how you could use this:

```
props = [list(np.random.rand(10)*20), list(np.random.rand(10)*10), list(np.random.rand(10)*30)]

for prop in normalize(array for array in props):
    print(prop)

for prop in normalize(props):
    print(prop)
```

I also tested the efficiency of your program against this one.

```
print(f"OLD: {timeit.timeit(old_normalize, number=100000)} seconds.")
print(f"NEW: {timeit.timeit(normalize, number=100000)} seconds.")
```

```
OLD: 2.7710679 seconds.
NEW: 0.0201071 seconds.
```

Comment: your method would not work on a read iterable. Did you try `list(normalize((i for i in range(3))))`. You need to create the array first, and then take the min and max from that. That will be a lot faster for largers arrays too

Comment: `mypy` also complains about the type annotations. It should be `def normalize(*iterables: Iterable[Any])` or `iterable[float]` if you want to limit the operation to numbers

Comment: [reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values)

Comment: @MaartenFabré Just updated, thanks for catching that.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Calling it with an iterable still will not work... you need something like this: `def normalize(*iterables: Iterable[Any]) -> np.array:
    for iterable in iterables:
        my_array = np.array(list(iterable))
        lower, upper = my_array.min(), my_array.max()
        yield (my_array - lower) / (upper - lower)`

Comment: @MaartenFabré I'm not really sure what you mean. Passing multiple types of iterables, including read iterables, has the expected output. What kind of iterables won't work that the OP requires? The most I see required are `list` and a read iterable since they state they might have ~10+ lists.

Comment: the 'read' was a typo. I meant real iterable, as in not a container. One that exhausts.`list(normalize((i for i in range(3))))` still doesn't work on your method

Comment: @MaartenFabré That makes a lot more sense. Thanks so much for the clarification. I'll community wiki this since you helped greatly in the process of fixing this answer.

Comment: Are you sure you included a `list` call in your timing? Because otherwise it is just the time needed to setup the generator.